# setInterval & setTimeout executing at the wrong time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background image using setInterval and setTimeout every x seconds but im strugling a bit. The problem is that the timer is not working as supposed to. It changes the images instantly.

```
    let images = ['background1.jpg', 'background2.jpg','background3.jpg'];

    let i = 0;
    $("main").css("background-image", 'url(' + images[i] + ')');

    setInterval(function(){ 
        setTimeout( function() {
            if(i == 0){
                i++;
                $('main').css({
                    'background-image': 'url(' + images[i] + ')',
                    'background-size': 'cover'
                });
            }
        },3000);
        setTimeout( function() {
            if(i == 1){
                i++;
                $('main').css({
                    'background-image': 'url(' + images[i] + ')',
                    'background-size': 'cover'
                });
            }
        },3000);
        setTimeout( function() {
            if(i == 2){
                i = 0;
                $('main').css({
                    'background-image': 'url(' + images[i] + ')',
                    'background-size': 'cover'
                });
            }
        },3000);
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Get the `main` element (Or the target)
2. Declare the CSS `background-size': 'cover` for DRY *(Don't Repeat Yourself)* coding.
3. Show the first image, and increase `i` to show the next one in the "loop"

```
// The images indexes holder
let i = 0;
// Set the first image (i = 0 for now)
el.style.backgroundImage = `url(${arr[i]})`;
// increase i, to prevent showing the first image twice (for the first 6 seconds).
i++;
```

- Finally, change the `background-image` every 3 sec. If reaches the last index, set to the first. And repeat...

**The Code:**

```js
//var images = ['background1.jpg', 'background2.jpg','background3.jpg'];
var images = ['https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg',
               'https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg',
               'https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg']

var main = document.querySelector("main");

const backgroundSlider = (el, arr) => {
    let i = 0;
    el.style.backgroundImage = `url(${arr[i]})`;
    i++;

    setInterval(() => {
        el.style.backgroundImage = `url(${arr[i]})`;
        i++;
        i == arr.length ? i = 0 : '';
    }, 3000);
};

backgroundSlider(main, images);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  background: center / contain no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code will not work because setTimeout is async. Your 3 updates are not done like 3s,6s,9s.
The three setTimeout statements are read in stepbystep order and the functions inside them are requested(in simple terms) to be run after 3s by each one of them.
They are all done after ~3s (almost  3s) delay.
So, in the end you see the last function run which has `i=0` and resets to the first image.

Edit: similar solution has been posted already. This one uses jQuery.

```
//This will run every 3s. 
setInterval(function(){ 
  i = (i+1)%3;
  $('main').css({'background-image': 'url(' + images[i] + ')',
'background-size': 'cover'
                });
    }, 3000);
```