# Repeat background images of a div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the background images of a div, but somehow it runs once and shows the last image and not iterating.

JS

```
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
let backImages = ['backimage1.jpg', 'backimage2.jpg', 'backimage3.jpg'];

// First way
setInterval(() => {
  for (let bg in backImages) {
    wrapper.style.background = `url('${backImages[bg]}')`;
  }
}, 3000);

// Second way
let changeBg = () => {
  for (let bg in backImages) {
    wrapper.style.background = `url('${backImages[bg]}')`;
  }
};

setInterval(changeBg, 3000);
```

How can I make it so that it keep iterating over all images endlessly.

Comment: What your code doing is: 1. wait 3 seconds, 2. Change the background images 3 times, go back to 1.  There is no delay between changing the background images so you can't see the first 2 images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setInterval & setTimeout executing at the wrong time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68248152/setinterval-settimeout-executing-at-the-wrong-time)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you need:

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
let backImages = ['backimage1.jpg', 'backimage2.jpg', 'backimage3.jpg'];
wrapper.style.background = `url('${backImages[0]}')`;
let startIndex = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  startIndex = startIndex + 1;
  if (startIndex == backImages.length) {
    startIndex = 0;
  }

  wrapper.style.background = `url('${backImages[startIndex]}')`;
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is because he function is doing the forloop all at once.

```
Start function after 3 seconds.
   Do ForLoop
     Change 1
     Change 2
     Change 3
Then Apply.
```

You'll want to have an iteration outside of that.

```
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
let backImages = ['backimage1.jpg', 'backimage2.jpg', 'backimage3.jpg'];

//Set a cycle count, and get the max number in your array.
var bgCycleCount = 0;
var bgCycleMax = backImages.length;


setInterval(() => {
    //Apply the BG for the current array position.
    wrapper.style.background = `url('${backImages[bgCycleCount]}')`;
    if(bgCycleCount == bgCycleMax) {
      bgCycleCount = 0; //Reset if you've reached the end
    } else {
      bgCycleCount++; //If not the end, increment the array position
    }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In both the case you are re starting to run the loop from the beginning.

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
let backImages = ['https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/2fz1zlPNq7cj7QkLAtKdqYrKvs0=/3704x2778/smart/filters:no_upscale()/the-difference-between-trees-and-shrubs-3269804-hero-a4000090f0714f59a8ec6201ad250d90.jpg',

  'https://www.sciencenewsforstudents.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/1030_LL_trees-1028x579.png', 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71WcZqPYToL._SL1200_.jpg'
];
let count = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  wrapper.style.background = `url('${backImages[count]}')`;
  count = count === backImages.length - 1 ? 0 : count + 1;
}, 3000);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'></div>
```